# How does set handle collision?

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, hashmap, set

Internally, a set is implemented by a map. The item value will be a key, and the value will be a dummy value. However, what happens if a collision happens in a set. In other words, the values from two items are used as keys and will be hashed into indices of an underlying array.

Questions:

1. what happens if the two indices are the same?
2. In hashmap, chaining will be used to solve the problem by chaining the
   values of the collided keys into a linked list?
3. If the collision happens in the underlying hashmap of the set, how
   do we solve this issue? In this case, only keys matter?

Comment: In a hash map, the nodes in the hash chain contain both keys and values.  Otherwise you couldn't tell which value corresponds to the key you're looking up.

Comment: `In this case, only keys matter?` In **every** case only the keys matter. The rest is just a matter of implementation.